# Ordnungswidrigkeit oder Vergehen

Tags: difference, word-choice, synonym

> **das Vergehen**: gegen ein Gesetz, eine Norm o. Ä. verstoßende Handlung
>
> **die Ordnungswidrigkeit**: 
>       ordnungswidriges Verhalten

Quelle: Duden

Besteht der Unterschied nur darin, dass die Ordnungswidrigkeit enger ist als ein Vergehen, d.h., dass die Ordnungswidrigkeit gegen die Ordnung auf den Straßen ist (Unrat auf der Straße lassen) und das Vergehen gegen irgendetwas Beliebiges?

Comment: Beachte, dass *Ordnung* in *Ordnungswidrigkeit* nicht im Sinne von *Reinlichkeit, Sauberkeit* oder *Aufgeräumtheit,* sondern im Sinne von *Regel, Gesetz* oder *Vorschrift* ist.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Schon dem Duden entnimmt man, dass „Ordnungswidrigkeit“ ausschließlich ein juristischer Fachbegriff ist, während „Vergehen“ auch in einem nicht technischen Sinne gebraucht wird. Als Fachbegriff bezeichnet „Vergehen“ jedoch eine [minderschwere Straftat](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vergehen), während eine Ordnungswidrigkeit noch [unterhalb einer Straftat](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordnungswidrigkeit) angesiedelt ist.

Comment: Also eine Ordnungswidrigkeit ist im juristischen Sinn weniger ernst als ein Vergehen?

Comment: @marmistrz Eine Ordnungswidrigkeit ist im juristischen Sinn weniger erst als eine Straftat. Ein Gesetz legt fest als was ein Verstoß zählt. Wenn nicht Juristen das Wort Vergehen verwenden können sowohl Ordnungswidrigkeiten als auch leichte Straftaten gemeint sein, wobei "leicht" hier subjektiv ist und nicht nach Höhe der Strafe bemessen wird. Laut wikipedia definiert das Gesetzbuch *Vergehen* als Straftaten deren Mindeststrafe unter einem Jahr liegt oder die nur zu einer Geldstrafe führen. Für schwerere Straftaten wird oft "Verbrechen" verwendet.